# How does iframe . contentWindow . document . execCommand work?

Tags: jquery, html, plugins

im trying to find out how this text editor work, iv been scanning through the script and can't seem to understand it.

[first this is the link for the demo](http://batiste.dosimple.ch/blog/posts/2007-09-11-1/rich-text-editor-jquery.html)

what i can't understand is when you click the bold button which triggers this

```
 $('.bold', tb).click(function(){ formatText(iframe, 'bold');return false; });
```

and then it gets send to the formatText function, and thats where i get lost, becuase thiers no mention of adding `<strong></strong>` tags to the text in the textarea, im really curious to know how it works, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function formatText(iframe, command, option) {
    iframe.contentWindow.focus();
    try{
        iframe.contentWindow.document.execCommand(command, false, option);
    }catch(e){console.log(e)}
    iframe.contentWindow.focus();
```

formatText is not a default jQuery function. I took the above from the js source of the editor. The first thing it does is focus on the iframe area where your text resides. You're not really typing in a textarea field, but rather in an iframe contentEditable div `<div contentEditable="true"></div>` since textarea does not support rich text editing. The function then issues the contentEditable  exexCommand to make the selected text Bold.

You can view a list of all execCommands at http://help.dottoro.com/larpvnhw.php

Comment: thanks for your answer is thier anyway, i can put the tags `<pre></pre>` between the texts thank you

Comment: This should be posted as another question. It irrelevant to your questions above.

Answer (score 1):

It uses [document.execCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536419%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is a tool for turning pages into 'editable' mode. Have a read through the description and [Command Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

It originated from IE but has been adopted into most modern browsers.

**Here's the function which uses it.**

```
function formatText(iframe, command, option) {
    iframe.contentWindow.focus();
    try{
        iframe.contentWindow.document.execCommand(command, false, option); //Right here
    }catch(e){console.log(e)}
    iframe.contentWindow.focus();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer is thier anyway, i can put the tags <pre></pre> between the texts thank you

Answer (score 0):

That text editor does not use `<textarea>`s, it uses `<iframe>`s.

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers implement a special API for WYSIWYG editing. First, it requires setting designMode = "On" on document object. After that you can use pre-defined commands that do the formatting, like

```
document.execCommand('bold', false, null);
```

You can find some information in the [Midas specification](http://www.mozilla.org/editor/midas-spec.html), that Firefox uses. IE has very similar API and even more [pre-defined commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).